# Adding support to Busybox vi for reading file from stdin

Tags: c, io, linux, embedded

I am writing a patch for [Busybox](http://busybox.net/)'s implementation of `vi`, the classical command line code editor and predecessor of `vim`. It can open up a files through filenames given as command line arguments. My patch allows initial text to be loaded in to the buffer through a pipe on standard input too.

```
# normal usage
vi file.txt
# with my patch ('-' tells vi to read from stdin)
ls -l | vi -
```

The Busybox project is a minimal implementation of many Unix commands, meant to be run on embedded devices and has a very small executable size. The project has a script to measure the executable size delta of two versions. Below is the output for my current implementation.

> ```
> function                                             old     new   delta
> fd_insert                                              -     292    +292
> edit_file                                           1299    1370     +71
> init_text_buffer                                     333     398     +65
> .rodata                                            88972   89004     +32
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> (add/remove: 1/0 grow/shrink: 3/0 up/down: 460/0)             Total: 460 bytes
> ```

[`init_text_buffer`](http://git.busybox.net/busybox/tree/editors/vi.c?id=b7ee7e1e13fa4a680e8b228bd158e7aa53fe342a#n717) does some initialisation and then calls  `file_insert` to read from the given filename. If it fails, the buffer will be left empty (spare a newline). `text` is a global pointer to the actual char buffer of the document.

I've modified this function to read from standard input if the filename argument is "-". `LONE_DASH` is a macro also used in other parts of Busybox.

```
if (fn && LONE_DASH(fn)) {
    rc = fd_insert(STDIN_FILENO, text);
} else {
    rc = file_insert(fn, text, 1);
}
```

[`file_insert`](http://git.busybox.net/busybox/tree/editors/vi.c?id=b7ee7e1e13fa4a680e8b228bd158e7aa53fe342a#n2907) was originally the only function to fill the text buffer with initial data. I haven't made any modifications to this function, but I used it as a template for `fd_insert`.

`text_hole_make` resizes the buffer if it's too small and returns the pointer delta.

`full_read` reads characters from a file descriptor into a buffer. The third argument is the maximum characters to read. It returns the number of characters read.

I wrote `fd_insert` from scratch to mimic the behaviour of `file_insert`, but to be able to read from file descriptors like `STDIN_FILENO`.

```
static int fd_insert(int fd, char *p)
{
    int size = BUFSIZ;
    int cnt = 0;
    int total = 0;

    do {
        total += cnt;
        p += text_hole_make(p + total, size);
        cnt = full_read(fd, p + total, size);
    } while (cnt == size);

    if (cnt < 0) {
        status_line_bold_errno("can't read from fd");
        if (total)  // un-do buffer insert
            p = text_hole_delete(p, p + total - 1, NO_UNDO);
        total = cnt;
    } else {
        total += cnt;
        // shrink unused space
        p = text_hole_delete(p + total, p + total + size - cnt - 1, NO_UNDO);
    }

    return total;
}
```

I've tried to remove the `fd` argument to reduce size, but this actually increased the size by 2 bytes (+7 to `fd_insert` and -5 to `init_text_buffer`).

There is some duplicated file reading logic in `file_insert` and `fd_insert`, but I'm not sure how to extract it. My goal is to reduce the executable size and to make my logic as clear as possible for others to read and maintain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Can be slightly smaller

I was able to shrink your function a little by combining the two calls to `text_hole_delete` into one call.  I'm not sure what compiler options you are using, but when I used `gcc -Os` on a 32-bit x86 target, it saved 16 bytes.  Here is the modified code:

```
int fd_insert(int fd, char *p)
{
    int size       = BUFSIZ;
    int cnt        = 0;
    int total      = 0;
    int unusedSize = 0;
    int ret        = 0;

    do {
        total += cnt;
        p     += text_hole_make(p + total, size);
        cnt    = full_read(fd, p + total, size);
    } while (cnt == size);

    if (cnt < 0) {
        status_line_bold_errno("can't read from fd");
        ret        = cnt;
        unusedSize = total;
    } else {
        total     += cnt;
        ret        = total;
        p         += total;
        unusedSize = size - cnt;
    }

    // shrink unused space
    if (unusedSize)
        text_hole_delete(p, p + unusedSize - 1, NO_UNDO);
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Combining the `text_hole_delete` calls reduced the size by 26 bytes on my machine. Thanks! I didn't use a `ret` variable as I think that part is clear enough.